# Официальный архив расширения SDL_image не имеет lib и хидеров

Tags: sdl

Вопрос очень узкоквалификационный, но у них на офф сайте отсутствуют lib и .h файлы в архиве, разчитанном на разработку под mingw компиляторы.Конкретно в графе Binary, хоть win32 хоть х64 архив. Где взять, чем заменить, почему-то же они раздают только dll библиотеки? http://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_image/release-1.2.html Мне нужна пока именно версия 1.2 SDL библиотеки, в версии 2.0 всё есть, но они не подходят.

Comment: Скачал сейчас по вашей ссылке тарбол с 1.2, внутри есть всё, что нужно — `.c`, `.h` файлы, make-файлы тоже там. Даже `Android.mk` есть. А в тарболах с бинарниками лежат готовые .dll и .so файлы (видимо для тех, кому сложно сделать `configure + make`). Так в чём у вас проблема-то?

Comment: Ну я просто хочу увидеть папку с тремя другими папками: include, lib и bin. А в binary графе только bin. Вы судя по всему предлагаете скомпилировать проект всё самостоятельно из source файлов. Но мне трудно что-то в tar архиве разобраться, что к чему.

Comment: Просто сделайте `./configure && make` и в директории `.libs` найдёте нужные вам статические и динамические библиотеки.

Comment: Ну вроде срослось всё. Спасибо.